# Integrating custom controller to ros_control package

Tags: microcontroller, ros-melodic, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am new to ROS and ros_control and I don't know how to integrate my custom controller into to the ros_control package. I have implemented [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control) and everything works OK. I can run default/existing controllers but I need to know how I can merge my new controller to the controller_manager.  In my workspace within src folder, I have three folders: rrbot_control, rrbot_description, and rrbot_gazebo and each has its own `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` files.

Right now I have a `.cpp` file of my new controller:

1. Where should I put it (in which folder)?
2. Shall I change `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` files? and how?

I'm using ROS melodic and ubuntu 18.04.
Thanks a lot for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357530/integrating-custom-controller-to-ros_control-package/) by [abata](https://answers.ros.org/users/56778/abata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found [this video](https://youtu.be/7BLc18lOFJw) and it is the answer to my question :)

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [abata](https://answers.ros.org/users/56778/abata/) with karma: 33 on 2020-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0